# Is the factory attribute for tomcat's server.xml required?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, apache-commons-dbcp

I have been reading more on JNDI in tomcat and I have read from multiple resources that the factory attributed is required. They say its often supposed to be "*org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory*". However, most often I see something like this -

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

So what does tomcat do in this case? Does it default to "*org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory*"?

Comment: ps. here is one of the sources http://vigilbose.blogspot.com/2009/03/apache-commons-dbcp-and-tomcat-jdbc.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` is not the default factory. It's the new Tomcat 7.0 builtin [high-performance connection pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) which is supposed to replace the default DBCP.

The default factory is the `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory`. See also the [JNDI resources HOW TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html). The attribute is indeed not required.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for. Last question, if I was to create my connection pool implementation (not for production but for a home project to learn) where would be a good place to start? I was thinking of just looking at the source code on tomcat-jdbc-pool. But maybe you have a better place to start.

Comment: [Here's](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html) a basic Sun/Oracle tutorial. Warning: the example implementation is very poor. Do not use it for real production! For example, it does not check nor limit the maximum amount of pooled connections.

Comment: Hmm i already saw that one. Yea it didn't really tell me anything I didn't know. I was going to just use a simple BlackingArrayQueue in Java that holds a pool of connections to see what the performance would be. I have an idea on where to start. I can't find the source for tomcat-jdbc-pool?

Comment: It are the ones with `src` in filename [here](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/). That link by the way comes from the linked related question :)